# How to make this Makefile more concise?

Tags: makefile

I know there are ways to remove duplicates `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $^` in Makefile. Can you tell me how to make the Makefile below more concise?

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-pthread -g -o

all: p1 p2

p1: p1.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $^

p2: p2.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your Makefile more concise, you can write it as follows.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-pthread -g -o

all: p1 p2

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $^
```

Then you can add as many p's as you want on the `all:` line. As long as you provide pN.c, make will compile them into the corresponding pN.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can combine commands "by prerequisite". For example:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-O3
INCLS=-I$(BASEDIR)/include
LIBS=$(BASEDIR)/lib/thread.a
OBJS = dotprod_mutex.o dotprod_serial.o
EXEC = dotprod

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
         $(CC) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
$(OBJS): dotprod.h
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLS) -c $*.c
```

or somesuch -- you'll need to go through the details and make sure those libraries and so on actually make sense.

Note that the phrase `$(OBJS): dotprod.h` means that `$(OBJS):` depends on the presence of `dotprod.h`.

You will want to read the manual to get all the gory details, in particular:

- [Letting Make deduce commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#make-Deduces)
- [Combine by prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Combine-By-Prerequisite)

As for tools to automate this stuff, you want automake and autoconf: http://sourceware.org/autobook/

Comment: snim2, thank you, my question is not very clear, and I changed it.

Comment: Thanks David. In that case either of the answers here will work, and do answer the question, as far as I can see :)